# Restoring Deleted auto-increment id?

Tags: sql, magento

Use of auto-increment property along with primary key is conman among people. if one delete a recorded from table (anywhere near to center), Is once can restore them (as they are related).

In Magento -  if one delete category,its product becomes orphan but once we update category, then he has to manually assign category product relation.Adding through code will result change in category-ID (auto-increment and EAV),  Product -ID follows the same if we delete and update.

Dose one can maintain category-ID and product-ID ? , any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd not recommend you to change the native way to handle categories ids. The better way, I think, is to create a new category attribute which will store static ids.

Comment: thanks for reply,this is cool for product, what about category and sub-category..

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/